# How to get source line number from a Python generator object?

Tags: python, generator

Here is an example:

```
def g():
  yield str('123')
  yield int(123)
  yield str('123')

o = g()

while True:
  v = o.next()
  if isinstance( v, str ):
    print 'Many thanks to our generator...'
  else:
    # Or GOD! I don't know what to do with this type
    raise TypeError( '%s:%d Unknown yield value type %s.' % \
                     (g.__filename__(), g.__lineno__(), type(v) )
                   )
```

How do I get the source file name and the exact yield line number, when my generator returns unknown type (int in this example)?

Comment: `v = g.next()` should be `v = o.next()` perhaps?

Answer (score 8):

Your generator object "o" in this case has all the information you want. You can paste your example into a Python console, and inspect with `dir` both the function "g" and the generator "o".

The generator has the attributes "gi_code" and "gi_frame" which contain the information you want:

```
>>> o.gi_code.co_filename
'<stdin>'
# this is the line number inside the file:
>>> o.gi_code.co_firstlineno
1
# and this is the current line number inside the function:
>>> o.gi_frame.f_lineno
3
```

Comment: o.gi_frame.f_lineno exactly, what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can get the information you want.  That's the sort of thing captured in exceptions, but there has been no exception here.

Comment: You are obviously in error, as the information is all there thorugh simple introspection